# Share validation code among different UITextFields

Tags: ios, validation, uitextfield, share, uitextfielddelegate

Maybe it's a simple question but I can't figure out the right way to do it.

I have a `UITextField`. Since I need to validate the text that is inserted within this text field, I'm currently using the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` like the following:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   // do validation here
   // return YES or NO depending on previous validation
}
```

Since I have some text fields (they not belong to the same controller where the validation is performed) and I don't want to duplicate text fields validation code, how can I achieve an elegant way to centralize a similar validation? I don't know if subclassing is the right way, but in this case I need to use the same delegation method (the one listed above) in different parts of the same app.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how much information your validation code requires. If the arguments of `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` are all you need to determine whether to return YES or NO, then you can just use the same delegate for all your textFields.

If you need to track and store information about previous validations in order to make validation decisions, the easiest way would be to package all that state up into an object, and have an array of those objects, each corresponding to a specific UITextField. Then, in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` you would use the state corresponding to the textField that was passed in.

Comment: +1 for your advice. But what do you mean with *you can just use the same delegate for all your textFields*? *UITextFields* can belong to different view controllers that contain them. Thank you.

Comment: I call your what do you mean, and raise you another what do you mean. There's no reason why two or more UITextFields couldn't be in different view controllers, but have the same delegate.

Comment: I see. You suggest to create a different class object that "implements" (adopts) a *UITextFieldDelegate* and then instantiate it within each controller where it is needed. Then set that delegate as the designated one for text fields. Is it right?

Comment: That's right. Or, depending on how your validation works, you might not even need to instantiate a copy of the delegate in each controller, and instead just pass the same one around. Although even in that case, it might be easier (and better MVC) to instantiate a new one in each view controller.